# How to identify javascript undeletable properties?

Tags: javascript, properties, ecmascript-5, strict-mode

In Javascript strict mode

> Deleting an undeletable property is not allowed

To make sure that one do not delete such an undeletable property, how do one figure out **property X** is deletable and **property Y** is undeletable

The concept behind it is......?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The concept behind this is...?

[Property attributes](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.1). Every property that has its `configurable` attribute set to `false` cannot be `delete`d (which fails silently in sloppy mode and throws in strict mode).

> How to figure out whether a property is deletable?

You can use the [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) to access the attributes as an object:

```
var isDeletable = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "propName").configurable;
```

Notice that this will only work for own properties of `obj`, not inherited ones; for those you will have to call the function on the respective prototype.

Comment: This was both fast and close to perfect! Thanks

Comment: @student: Only close to?! Please tell me what I could improve, or suggest an edit :-)

Comment: Because we live in an [un-ideal](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/nobody-is-perfect-im-nobody--2.png) world ;)